# Why was my question about bitcoin closed?

Tags: discussion

The question was:

[Is the cryptocurrency Bitcoin a pyramid scheme?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39866/is-the-cryptocurrency-bitcoin-a-pyramid-scheme)

It was a re-work of another closed question:

[Is bitcoin a pyramid scheme?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39797/is-bitcoin-a-pyramid-scheme)

Pyramid schemes are defined quite well and have certain characteristics. Why is it considered opinion based?

Also, bitcoin lovers will always be biased in support of it because they will lose money if price goes down. So, they always need to have to make a positive image for it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to see the question:

1. Does bitcoin match the literal definition of pyramid scheme?
2. Is bitcoin a bad investment, bubble or otherwise scammy business?

In the meaning 1 the question is off topic as non factual, nor we can safely assume our interpretation of intent is correct, in the meaning 2 the question is opinion based.

Is the question representing the claim fairly that btc is literally a pyramid scheme? Because I think all it was meant is "it's a big bubble" and we are not really addressing the point as it was meant, so we're just adding noise to the internet.
In other words. I dispute the notability of the literal interpretation.

In either case, 1 or 2, the question needs work so I closed it.